# Multiple Errors: Parse.com java.lang.RuntimeException: bolts.AggregateException

Tags: java, android, exception, parse-platform, runtime

I get a runtime error sometimes, shown below.

I think it happens due to some change in my wifi but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know why this error occurs? How do we fix it? I was unable to find anything using Google.

The  code that causes the problem is:

```
//make new object 
ParseObject LogNew = new ParseObject("Log");
//make file
file = new ParseFile("_"+getHashedID()+"_"+fileNames[i], fileContent);
//put file 
LogNew.put("EmailLog"+i, file);
try {
    **LogNew.save();**
} catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The save is at ParseService.521, which is what it is complaining about.

```
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8879
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385): Process: com.youplusplus, PID: 16385
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385): java.lang.RuntimeException: bolts.AggregateException: There were multiple errors.
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at com.parse.Parse.waitForTask(Parse.java:881)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at com.parse.ParseObject.save(ParseObject.java:1337)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at com.youplusplus.ParseService.ParseForLogs(ParseService.java:521)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at com.youplusplus.ParseService$Task.run(ParseService.java:771)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385): Caused by: bolts.AggregateException: There were multiple errors.
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$3.then(Task.java:246)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$3.then(Task.java:228)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at         bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:307)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:304)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at com.parse.ParseFile$3$1.then(ParseFile.java:433)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at com.parse.ParseFile$3$1.then(ParseFile.java:426)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:307)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:304)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:314)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:325)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:481)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at         bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:314)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:325)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:481)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:342)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$6.then(Task.java:339)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:307)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$5.then(Task.java:304)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:506)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(Task.java:577)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setError(Task.java:604)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:487)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$10$1.then(Task.java:481)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:440)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:27)
11-01 10:51:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(16385):    at bolts.
```

Comment: You need to show a minimal sample of your code that replicates the error, as well as the error, in order to get useful answers.